# When iPad rotates scrollview not lined up with top of screen

Tags: ipad, ios5, uiscrollview, ios-simulator, rotation

When the iPad simulator changes orientation the contents of the uiscrollview no longer are aligned to the top. When the app starts in landscape all is well - the controls contained in the scrollview which should be the top most are at the top. The same is true when it starts in portrait.
However, when it is rotated there is a large gap at the top if it was from landscape to portrait or many of those at the top are off the top of screen if it rotates from portrait to landscape.
Does anyone have any ideas what I should be looking at in order to fix this, please?

Thanks

Comment: This may sound overly simplistic, but did you make sure you UIScrollView is anchored top, bottom, left, and right with stretching in vertical and horizontal directions?

Comment: Not at all - this solved my problem. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Rob says - needed to make sure the UIScrollView is anchored top, bottom, left, and right with stretching in vertical and horizontal directions.